# Remove duplicate value in csv on combine

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I encountered the below code online and modified this on my need.
I just wanna ask since i am new to batch file if there is a way to remove duplicate values after the combine.

```
@echo off

ECHO Set working directory
pushd %~dp0

ECHO Deleting existing combined file
del combined.csv

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


set cnt=1


for %%i in (*.csv) do (
  if !cnt!==1 (
    for /f "delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
  ) else if %%i NEQ combined.csv (
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
  )
  set /a cnt+=1
)
```

Comment: Please read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and also the help topic [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to learn how to use this site!

Comment: Are you referring to header lines. If so you can delete all and add one header line at the top.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

ECHO Set working directory
pushd %~dp0

ECHO Deleting existing combined file
del combined.csv

set "flag="

for %%i in (*.csv) do if %%i NEQ combined.csv (
 IF DEFINED flag (
  findstr /l /x /v /g:combined.csv "%%i">#.vsc
  TYPE #.vsc >>combined.csv
 ) ELSE (
  COPY  "%%i" combined.csv >nul
  SET flag=y
 )
)
DEL #.vsc /F /Q
POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

This may suit you better.

It uses a simple `setlocal` rather than the `delayedexpansion` version, initialising `flag` to *empty* then setting it within the loop and using `if defined` which works on the run-time value of `flag`.

First time through, it simply copies the detected source file to `combined.csv` and then sets `flag` to *a value* so it's ow **defined**

each other time through, `findstr` outputs those lines in the source file `%%i` that `/v` do **not** `/x` exactly match `/l` literally `/g:filename` any line in the `combined.txt` file TO a tempfile I'be nominated as `#.vsc` (name not important). Then *that* file is appended to `combined.csv`

Consequently, provided any particular `.csv` is free of duplicate lines within itself, the `combined.csv` will also be free of duplicate lines.

Since the header line is evidently identical in every file, the initial `copy` of the first file will place the header into `combined.csv` and hence `findstr` will neatly exclude it thereafter.

---

Revision to combat evil unicode:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

ECHO Set working directory
pushd %~dp0

ECHO Deleting existing combined file
del combined.csv

set "flag="
for %%i in (*.csv) do if %%i NEQ combined.csv (
 (FOR /f "delims=" %%j IN ('type "%%i"') DO ECHO %%j)>#.vsc
 IF DEFINED flag (
  findstr /l /x /v /g:combined.csv "#.vsc" >##.vsc
  TYPE ##.vsc>>combined.csv
 ) ELSE (
  REN #.vsc combined.csv
  SET flag=y
 )
)
DEL #.vsc /F /Q
DEL ##.vsc /F /Q
POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

I suspect that the problem is using UNICODE within your files. Cutting-and-pasting your data showed that it was unicode.

The `for /f...` ceremony reads unicode and produces ASCII, hence this version first simply converts to ASCII using your familiar technique then operates on the converted file `#.vsc`. `findstr` does not appreciate outputting to the same file as it's attempting to read as `/g:`, so a further tempfile `##.vsc` is used for the `findstr` output.

Note that the unicode characters between (header) `Last modified` and `date` and also elsewhere will be replaced by question-marks.

Comment: As per running the bat with your suggestion what happen is the header of the other file is still present.
and there are still duplicates

Comment: Are the file-headers identical?

Comment: Yes the header are identical i check this multiple times.

Comment: the issue is due to the new file were inserted in the end and not in a new line

Comment: Not yet.Still facing the issue.Is there a code in bat/batch to be sure that the new insert is in a new line?

Comment: I don't understand. Please provide an example.

Comment: What happen is this :
_OrderId|ItemCd|CostumerId|OrderStatus|OrderDate|LastModifiedDate
0011|Dry-Goods|0000120|Completed|2016-09-27T14:49:18-04:00|2016-09-27T14:49:18-04:00
0014|Dry-Goods|0000123|Completed|2016-09-27T14:49:18-04:00|2016-09-27T14:49:18-04:00
0019|Dry-Goods|0000128|InProgress|2016-09-27T14:49:18-04:00|2016-09-27T14:49:18-04:00OrderId|ItemCd|CostumerId|OrderStatus|OrderDate|LastModifiedDate
0011|Dry-Goods|0000120|Completed|2016-09-27T14:49:18-04:00|2016-09-27T14:49:18-04:00........_